# AmCharts 5 Maps. how to find zoom level?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

How to find current zoom Level on wheel event in amcharts 5?

v4 got document below. but there is no document for the same in v5.

[https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/setting-initial-zoom-and-position-of-a-map-chart/#:~:text=Finding%20zoom%20level%20and%20point&text=Zoom%20and%20position%20it%20exactly,by%20accessing%20map's%20zoomLevel%20attribute](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/setting-initial-zoom-and-position-of-a-map-chart/#:%7E:text=Finding%20zoom%20level%20and%20point&text=Zoom%20and%20position%20it%20exactly,by%20accessing%20map%27s%20zoomLevel%20attribute).

I have tried the below code, it doesn't work properly

```
 chart.events.on("wheel", function(ev) {
      console.log(chart._downZoomLevel);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution.

```
chart._settings.zoomLevel
```